# Functor Connected Component and Indescrete functor

Tags: category-theory

i have the next doubts about the following functors:

1)
$Ind: Set\rightarrow Cat$

Which  $Ind(A)$ is the category whose objects are elements of $A$, i mean 
$Obj(Ind(A))=A$, And $Hom_{Ind(A)}(x,y)=\{x\rightarrow y\}$, in other words, there is an unique morphism of $x$ to $y$.

My question is: is that assignment correct?, because the only thing i am doing  is putting an arrow between each element of $A$

2)$Comp: Cat\rightarrow Set$

Which  $Comp(C)$ is the set of connected component of $C$.

What does that mean? Because i have been looking for the definition of connected component of one category and i have not had any luck.

Thank you for everything.

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes it is correct.

2) A pair of objects $A$ and $B$ in a category $\mathbb{C}$ are connected if there exists for some $n$ objects $X_1$, ... , $X_n$ in $\mathbb{C}$ such that $X_1=A$ and $X_n=$B and the set $\hom(X_i,X_{i+1})\cup \hom(X_{i+1},X_i)$ is non-empty for each $i\in \{1,..,n-1\}$.

A connected component $\mathbb{S}$ of a category $\mathbb{C}$ is a maximal subset of the objects of $\mathbb{S} \subseteq \mathbb{C}_0$ whose elements are pairwise connected (i.e. for each $A$ and $B$ in $\mathbb{S}$, $A$ and $B$ are connected in $\mathbb{C}$).

Comment: Thank you for the number one. For the number two is it means that  one element in the connected element of a category  $C$  is one objects in $C$ which is pair connected with all the elements in the   connected component of $C$?

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Nex 2) is correct, but note that the functor $Comp$ is more commonly denoted by $\pi_0$.

Moreover, 1) is correct too. Indeed, since the name $Ind$ stands for "indiscrete", hence is an hint that you are looking for a category with only one connected component.

In addition, you can note that there is also an (obvious) functor between $\mathbf{Set}$ and $\mathbf{Cat}$, usually called the free functor $\mathbf{F}$, that maps a set to a discrete category. This free functor is "the" right adjoint to the functor $\pi_0$ (aka $Comp$). For any set $A$, the category $\mathbf{F}(A)$ has as many connected components as there are objects in $A$.